# Radio Button won't stay check if I have a modal window open up when it is selected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modal-dialog

In a asp.net web project when the user selects a radio button I need a modal window to open up and prompt for user credentials.

I have the "TargetControlID" set to the radio button. The modal opens up just fine but when it goes away the radio button isn't checked.

EDIT:

```
Removed code for personal reasons
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Modal goes away, just recheck the radio button

`$("radio button").attr('checked',true);`

Comment: Makes sense. Where would I put that though?

Comment: After it is checked the modal pops up, what causes it to go away?

Comment: I added the code. The unixCancel and unixSubmit buttons allow it to go away.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.  <asp:Button ID="unixSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="<script type='text/javascript'> $('rdoUnix').attr('checked',true);</script>" />

Comment: Are you using jquery? if not the regular javascript would be

var cancel = document.getElementById('checkBoxId');
cancel.setAttribute('checked', 'true');

Comment: Thanks, I am using Jquery...and it simply won't work. This is the script I have:  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#unixSubmit').click(function () {
        $("rdoUnix").attr('checked', true);
    });
</script>

Comment: STRANGE! It is keeping the radio button in Google Chrome but not IE.

Comment: Yes, some things have to be done differently for cross browser compatibility. Jquery is useful because its cross browser compatible and detect which browser is being used then generates accordingly.

Comment: I am using Jquery - I'll edit my original post to reflect this code.

Comment: Looks good, however if that is the code your actually using you need the # sign in front of rdoUnix for it to work

Comment: Thank you for the quick fix, but for whatever reason this still refuses to work in Internet Explorer. =/