# My modal window is not transferring values to vb.net codebehind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cross-browser, modal-dialog

I am getting the username and password to run some scripts

```
  <act:ModalPopupExtender ID="unixLoginMPE" runat="server" TargetControlID="rdoUnix"
        PopupControlID="unixPanel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="unixCancel" OkControlID="unixSubmit"
          />
    <asp:Panel ID="unixPanel" runat="server" 
        CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" Style="display: none">Unix Username: <asp:TextBox ID="unixName" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"  />
        <br />
        Unix Password: <asp:TextBox ID="unixPass" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="Password"  />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="unixCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
        <asp:Button ID="unixSubmit" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="enableRDO()"  />
    </asp:Panel>
```

In my codebehind, I'm doing something like this just to test if the values have passed.

```
Dim UNIXPASSWORD As String = unixPass.text
                Dim UNIXUSERNAME As String = unixName.Text
                MsgBox(UNIXCOMPUTERNAME)
                MsgBox(UNIXUSERNAME)
                MsgBox(UNIXPASSWORD)
```

I do reference a script to enable the radio button. I asked a question to help me with that issue, it is all resolved [Radio Button won't stay check if I have a modal window open up when it is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562598/radio-button-wont-stay-check-if-i-have-a-modal-window-open-up-when-it-is-select/11562667#comment15299073_11562667)

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function enableRDO() {
            var cancel = document.getElementById('rdoUnix');
            cancel.setAttribute('checked', 'true');
        };
    </script>
```

For some reason the values are passing just fine in Google Chrome but not in IE. I've been at this for a few hours and don't know what else to try...or search for

EDIT:

I'm still trying to attempt this. I setup up dummy text boxes which I will hide later on if I can pass to them. I'm still very lost with this...

```
<asp:TextBox ID="dummyUnixName" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="dummyUnixPass" runat="server" />
```

Comment: You're using VB's MsgBox function in server-side code? System.Console.WriteLine would be better (Actual logging would be even better than that). It would also be helpful to see what the click event handler for unixSubmit is doing and what your page_load is doing.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to System.Console.WriteLine. So maybe this is my issue then...I don't have anything going on for the click event handler, I was having the OnClientClick handle everything. Also there is nothing in my page load for this.

Comment: If you are doing everything on the client, then, by definition, nothing would happen server side...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't performing a postback or an AJAX call, nothing will be passed to the code behind.

During debugging, Console.WriteLine can be redirected to the output window in VS; in production, it's going to go nowhere. A logging solution is often appropriate for a web application which needs to know more of what happened than which page was requested by a user (IIS logs).

Comment: Could I do this in my codebehind? This is the subroutine that is attached to OnClick.     Protected Sub SaveData(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        dUnixName.Text = unixName.Text
        dUnixPass.Text = unixPass.Text
  

    End Sub

Comment: That seems more in keeping with what you are trying to do.

Comment: I tried it and it isn't populating the text field. I fear this has something to do with postbacks...which I haven't really wrapped my head on how to implement. :(

Comment: If you're running in debug, try setting a breakpoint in the click handler and see if you actually hit it when you click on the button which is supposed to generate the postback... For starters, you should attach the event you want to fire, to the the OnClick. I'd suggest starting by messing around with a simpler page to get the ASP.Net Web Forms page lifecycle in your head...

Comment: Which part is working? Are you making your connections from client code or from the server side? What are you trying to do in the code-behind (that is, what is the server supposed to do here)?

Comment: This is working in my SaveData subroutine " dUnixName.Text = unixName.Text
        dUnixPass.Text = unixPass.Text" it will populate the text fields dUnixName and dUnixPass but not in IE. I just want the server to bring the form fields from the modal window and allow me to use them.

Comment: I hate bombarding Stack Overflow with these types of questions when I hit a wall...but I'm not sure what else to do :(